# removing quotes in PHP a bit complicated maybe

Tags: php

I have this peace of code which brings string searches for img tags in it and adds class to img tags. Then I save everything back and send it to database.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {

    if($img->getAttribute('class')){
    } 
    else {
        $img->setAttribute('class', 'someclass');
        $article_header = $doc->saveXml();
    }
}
```

Problem is that the result becomes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> <html><body><p><img
src="&quot;some_url/some_pic.jpg&quot;"
alt="&quot;&quot;" width="&quot;528&quot;"
height="&quot;722.0512820512821&quot;"
class="someclass"/></p></body></html>
```

So how can I get rid of this quot; things ???
I've read that it's phps magic quotes and tryied stripslashes on them like this

```
$article_header = stripslashes($doc->saveXml());
```

But this doesn't help.

**UPDATE**

```
<img width="\"528\"" height="\"722.0512820512821\"" alt="\"\"" src="%5C%22sources/public/users/103/articles/2011-06-11/3/img/1170x1600.gif%5C%22">
```

This kind of weird code I get from TinyMCE editor. Before I do DOM things to it. As I see it's already damaged. I wonder how :(

**UPDATE 2**

Problem found This was because of this

```
$article_header=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['article_header']);
```

If I remove **mysql_real_escape_string** everything is ok. But New question if I do so, what should I use instead of it to add some security to my script?

**SOLVED**
I removed mysql_real_escape_string and use them only when I'm passing data to mysql

Comment: I doubt magic quotes has anything to do with it. Slashes won't either. We need to see `$article_header`...

Comment: Why can't `if($img->getAttribute('class')){}  else { //...` not just be `if(!$img->getAttribute('class')){ //...`?

Comment: Also, `mysql_real_escape_string` shouldn't be HTML encoding your text. It should turn `"` to `\"` not `&quot;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED I removed mysql_real_escape_string and use them only when I'm passing data to mysql

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand reason of this problem but you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode();` to convert `&quot;` to `"`

Answer (score 0):

Well, these `&quot;` is a `"` character, so you can't stripslashes these characters as they are not `"` itself, just representation of them. You can do `str_replace("&quot;", '"', $string);`, but that's not the best answer, as you should escape `"` before inserting to db, then you'll get needed result.

Comment: Your code will not work. `str_replace("&quot;", "\"", $string);`

Answer (score 0):

you code should be:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {

    if(!$img->getAttribute('class')){
        $img->setAttribute('class', 'someclass');
    }
}
$article_header = $doc->saveXml();
```

update: for the next question, is enough that you are using DomDocument as he's parsing all the data and will give error if something is wrong.

when you want to save it to mysql you add `mysql_real_escape_string()` for security ..

Comment: It's not answer this question

Comment: @RiaD I was pointing 1 mistake ... as he saves XML every time an image doesn't have a class ... my guess is that ``$article_header`` has only one image with no class and now works, but next time it won't work! BTW, I updated ...